# How can I change USD to INR using PHP

Tags: php

I am searching for USD to INR converter in PHP. I found many solutions on StackOverflow but these are not working.

I tried this code -

```
<?php

$amount = 1.00;
$from_Currency = 'USD';
$to_Currency = 'INR';
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
$get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
$get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
echo $converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);


?>
```

It's not working.

I have tried another code for that -

Another PHP code -

```
function get_currency($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount) {
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);

    $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency";

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
                 "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
    $data = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]);

    return round($data[0], 2);
}

// Call the function to get the currency converted
echo get_currency('USD', 'INR', 1);
```

It's producing only 0 value. All solutions are not working for me. I tried all the solutions from StackOverflow.

Comment: open the url in browser that you are sending request. Is it working?

Comment: No, It's not working .

Comment: I have posted answer, this api is working.

Comment: Yes, Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Fetching JSON
$req_url = 'https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD';
$response_json = file_get_contents($req_url);

// Continuing if we got a result
if(false !== $response_json) {

    // Try/catch for json_decode operation
    try {

    // Decoding
    $response_object = json_decode($response_json);

    // YOUR APPLICATION CODE HERE, e.g.
    $base_price = 1; // Your price in USD
    echo $INR_price = round(($base_price * $response_object->rates->INR), 2);

    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // Handle JSON parse error...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's working. Thank you, Sachin.

Comment: can you please vote up the answer?

Comment: Do you have another solution using any other Google API? and I upvoted you .

Comment: Google does some changes with their APIs last year and most of the APIs are paid now. I am afraid they made converter API paid. Let me check for you.

Comment: I have tried your code but it's taking lot of time to execute.

Comment: @VishalRana - I have tried at my side and working fine.
if(false !== $response_json) - take out your code from this IF part and then try.